# Is CH₃CH(CH₂CH₃)₂ the same as CH₃CH(CH₃CH₂)₂

Tags: organic-chemistry

The carbon in front of the parenthesis is bonded to 2 CH2 which then bonded to CH3, it cannot bond directly to CH3. I assume the correct way of writing the formula of this molecule will be CH₃CH(CH₂CH₃)₂.

However, the university lecturer says its ok to write CH₃CH(CH₃CH₂)₂ because it is a common knowledge that CH3 cannot bond to both CH2 and C at the same time which indicate that the carbon in front of the parenthesis is bonded to CH2.

Trying to understand the lecturer's explanation, does it mean that in a parenthesis, it doesn't matter whether one person writes the order of bonding forward or backward and it is up to the reader to figure out whether the carbon in front of the parenthesis is bonded to the first or the last carbon in the parenthesis?

I am a non-native English speaker and I hope my question is explained clearly. Tried my best to phase this. Please let me know if any part of the question does not make sense.

Comment: The first way in the title is the normal way, the second is an abnormal rendition. Yes the second way can be puzzled out, but why make it hard on the reader?

Comment: Calcium acetate is sometimes written as (CH3COO)2Ca, sometimes Ca(CH3COO)2. Regardless of which way is correct, it is the same compound.

Comment: @MaxW So the order does not matter, it is just courtesy to write in the correct way according to the order of bonding. Do I understand this correctly? Me being too accurate, answered a test question and said these two are not the same molecule, got mark down for my answer.

Comment: @DanL - It is much more than a *courtesy,* but your teacher is right they are the same molecule. Frankly I think asking if the two are the same molecule on a test is a stupid question, but just let it go. If your teacher says the earth is flat, then in that classroom the earth is flat.

Comment: @MaxW the earth is flat until one can report him while not getting caught ;)